# Make ArrayList<?> containing different objects parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I have two kinds of custom objects `Movie` and `DetailedMovie` which are stored into an `ArrayList<Object>`. After doing a network operation my `ArrayList` is populated exclusively with either objects of type `Movie` or of type `DetailedMovie`. I am using a list of type object because they are linked to an adapter and the adapter then sorts out the views depending on what type of object is in the list.

So, the problem is that I want to store the contents of the ArrayList into a Bundle in onSaveInstanceState. Both my Movie and DetailedMovie objects implement Parcelable, but when I try

```
List<Object> mObjectMovieList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_LIST_KEY, mObjectMovieList);
}
```

I am told

`Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>'`

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being for this is that `Object` class do not extend `Parcelable`.

**1st Option**

One of the solution that I can suggest here is to make a parent class that extends `Parcelable` and then both  `Movie` and `DetailedMovie` extend that class.

So, it would look like:

```
List<MovieWrapper> mObjectMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `MovieWrapper` is parent of `Movie` and `DetailedMovie`

```
class Movie extends MovieWrapper 

class DetailedMovie extends MovieWrapper
```

**2nd Option**

The other option is to filter the array into specific type and then call `putParcelableArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Movie> movieList = mObjectMovieList.stream().filter(p->p instanceOf Movie).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
ArrayList<DetailedMovieList> detailedMovieList = mObjectMovieList.stream().filter(p->p instanceOf DetailedMovieList).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_LIST_KEY, movieList);
outState.putParcelableArrayList(DETAILED_MOVIE_LIST_KEY, detailedMovieList);
```

You may need to amend the above code as it is just a suggestion and can be changed as required.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it doesn't work. Would MovieWrapper class have the overridden functions filled out or would I only do that in in Movie and DetailedMovie respectively? Also, will this affect my adapter?

Comment: @CodeNovice There is no need to implement functions inside MovieWrapper. Infact,  you can just make MovieWrapper as an interface and use it as shared above and let the implementation of overridden function be inside corresponding classes only. Also, it depends how your adapter has been implemented but it should not affect your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure you use only Parcelable you may as well cast your list like this and lint ignore eventual uncast warning

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_LIST_KEY,(ArrayList<Parcelable>) mObjectMovieList);
```

Comment: This worked with the `(ArrayList)` cast, but it's since been edited to include `<Parcelable>` and that doesn't work so perhaps it needs to be edited out. Thanks @Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Parcelable` list then:

```
List<Parcelable> mObjectMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can add both `Movie` and `DetailedMovie` objects.

When you retrieve the object on the other side you'll have to distinguish them with

```
if (obj instanceof Movie) { ... }
```

A better option would be to have a base custom class implement `Parcelable` and being extended by your two classes.

You'd just use `List<MyBaseClass> mObjectMovieList = new ArrayList<>()` in this case.

If the base class exposes enough behavioral methods, you may need not to use `instanceof`, which would be a preferable situation.

Comment: Thank you! Voted up